# Laravel 4.2 HasMany Relationship using Like

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm wondering if its possible to set the operator when using a HasMany relationship in Laravel 4.2.

I'm working with a users table and an email log table. The log table has a userID stored in serialised format (as there may be more than one userID stored within the log).

Users table

```
+---------+
| user_ID |
+---------+
|       1 |
|       2 |
+---------+
```

emailLog Table

```
+----+--------------------+
| ID |       user_ID      |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";} |
|  2 | a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";} |
+----+--------------------+
```

Am I able to use a hasMany relation with a 'Like' operator rather than an equals operator to return the correct email log ID? Would the statement be written something like the below?

`return $this->hasMany('emailLog', 'user_ID', '%user_ID%', 'LIKE');`

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to return join table with a where clause would be:

return $this->hasMany('emailLog','user_id')->where('user_id', 'LIKE', '%user_id%');

Comment: This won't work as the SQL generated is `select * from [emailLog] where [user_ID] LIKE '%userID%' and [emailLog].[user_ID] in ('1')`. The SQL needs to be like `select * from [emailLog] where [user_ID] LIKE '%userID%'`

Comment: In that case, the hasMany would not be suitable to query that, the method EmailLog::where('user_id', 'LIKE', '%'.$this->user_id.'%'); should do it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do something similar

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function emailLogs()
    {
        // old code
        // return $this->hasMany(EmailLogs::class, 'user_ID');

        // Replace HasMany by like query
        return EmailLogs::where('user_ID', 'LIKE', "%{$this->user_ID}%");
    }
}
```